# How to copy a sentence from a longer string into a new array while including period?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I want to save part of a string into a new char array while including the period. For example, the string is:

```
My name is John. I have 1 dog.
```

I want to copy each char up to and including the first period, so the new char array will contain:

```
My name is John.
```

The code I have written below copies only "My name is John" but omits the period. 
ptrBeg and ptrEnd point to the char at the beginning and end, respectively, of the portion I want to copy. My intention was to copy ptrBeg into array newBuf through a pointer to newBuf and then increment both ptrBeg and the pointer to the array until ptrBeg and ptrEnd point to the same char, which should always be a period.

At this point, the text of the string should be copied, so I increment the pointer to char array once more and copy the period to the new space using

```
++ptrnewBuf;
*ptrnewBuf = *ptrEnd";
```

Finally, I print the contents of newBuf.
Here's the total code:

```
int main()
{
    char buf[] = "My name is John. I have 1 dog.";
    char * ptrBuf;
    char * ptrBeg;
    char * ptrEnd;
    ptrBeg = buf;
    ptrBuf = ptrBeg;
    while   (*ptrBuf != '.'){
        ptrBuf++;
    }

    ptrEnd = ptrBuf;

    char newBuf[100];
    char * ptrnewBuf = newBuf;

    while(*ptrBeg != *ptrEnd){
        *ptrnewBuf = *ptrBeg;
        ptrnewBuf++;
        ptrBeg++;
    }
    ++ptrnewBuf;
    *ptrnewBuf = *ptrEnd;
    printf("%s", newBuf);
}
```

How would I modify this code to include a period?

Comment: simply `ptrEnd = ptrBuf + 1;` You're fine in this case, but more generally you'll want to check that the `+ 1` stays within bounds of your buffer.

Comment: For general work, your loop `while (*ptrBuf != '.'){` should also check for end of string: `while (*ptrBuf != '.' && *ptrBuf != '\0'){`.  You need to ensure you null terminate the copied string; you need to copy up to and including (rather than just up to) the data pointed at by `ptrEnd` (aka `ptrBuf` — the values are the same when you enter the copying loop).  You could simply copy as you go, too — one loop instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you may be making things a bit more complicated than needed and overlooking a few critical checks. The key to iterating by pointers or using pointer arithmetic is to always validate and protect your array or memory bounds during each iteration or arithmetic operation.

Another tip is to always map out your pointer positions on a piece of paper before coding everything up so you have a clear picture of what your iteration limits and any adjustments need to be. (you don't have to use full long strings and many boxes, just use a representation of what needs to be done with a handful of characters) In your case where you wish to copy the substing up through the first `'.'`, something simple like the following will do, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | . |   | B | . |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
^   ^
|   pointer (when *p == '.')
buf
```

So to copy `"A."` from `buf` to a `new` buffer you can't simply iterate `while (*p != '.')` or you will not copy `'.'`. By drawing it out, you can clearly see you need to also copy the character when `p == '.'`, e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| A | . |   | B | . |\0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
^       ^
|   |-->| pointer (p + 1)
buf
```

Now regardless of the actual length of the string before `'.'`, you now know you need `p + 1` as the final address to include the last character in the copy.

You also know how many characters your `new` buffer can store. Say the size of `new` is `MAXC` characters (maximum number of characters). So you can store a string of at most `MAXC-1` characters (plus the *nul-character*). When you are filling `new` you need to always validate you are within `MAXC-1` characters.

You also need to insure you new string is *nul-terminated* (or it isn't a string, it's simply an array of characters). One effective way to insure nul-termination is by initializing all characters in new to `0` when it is declared, e.g.

```
char new[MAXC] = "";
```

which initializes the 1st character to `0` (e.g. `'\0'` empty-string) and all remaining characters `0` by default. Now if you fill no more than `MAXC-1` characters, you are guaranteed the array will be a nul-terminated string.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 128    /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buf[] = "My name is John. I have 1 dog.",
        *p = buf,               /* pointer to buf */
        new[MAXC] = "",         /* buffer for substring */
        *n = new;               /* pointer to new */
    size_t ndx = 0;             /* index for new */

    /* loop copying each char until new full, '.' copied, or end of buf */
    for (; ndx + 1 < MAXC && *p; p++, n++, ndx++) {
        *n = *p;        /* copy char from buf to new */
        if (*n == '.')  /* if char was '.' break */
            break;
    }

    printf ("buf: %s\nnew: %s\n", buf, new);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `ndx` is incremented as part of the `for` loop to track the number of characters copied with the pointers)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_cpy_substr
buf: My name is John. I have 1 dog.
new: My name is John.
```

If you do not have the luxury of initializing the string to insure nul-termination, you can always affirmatively nul-terminate after your copy is done. For example, you could add the following after the `for` loop exit to insure an array of unknown initialization is properly terminated:

```
    *++n = 0;   /* nul-terminate (if not already done by initialization) and
                 * note ++n applied before * due to C operator precedence.
                 */
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just breaking it out into a helper function that "extracts" the first sentence from a line. Just copies the characters over one at a time until either an end of string condition is hit on the source, the period is found, or a max length of the destination buffer is encountered.

```
void ExtractFirstSentence(const char* line, char* dst, int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    char c ='\0';

    if ((line == NULL) || (dst == NULL) || (size <= 0))
    {
        return;
    }


    while ((*line) && ((count+1) < size) && (c != '.'))
    {
        c = *line++;
        *dst++ = c;
        count++;
    }

    *dst = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char buf[] = "My name is John. I have 1 dog.";
    char newBuf[100];
    ExtractFirstSentence(buf, newBuf, 100);
    printf("%s", newBuf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want something a bit easier without dealing with all those pointers, try :

```
int main()
{
   char buf[] = "My name is John. I have 1 dog.";
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   while(buf[i] != '.' && buf[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
   }
    char newbuf[i+1];
    while (j <= i) {
        newbuf[j] = buf[j];
        j++;
    }
    newbuf[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",newbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

though the i+1 when making newbuf and the newbuff[j] = '\0' im not 100% certain need to be that way. my thoughts are the i+1 is needed to make room for the \0 ending which is then added after the while loop copying buf to newbuf.  but i could be mistaken.

Comment: Buffer overfow here: `newbuf[j] = '\0';`. You should make `newbuf` one byte longer. Hint: never use `<=`, instead increment `i` if `buf[i] == '.'`.

Comment: i thought the line :
char newbuf[i+1];   
is making newbuf one byte longer. when i run this code it works without error.

Comment: `i` is the offset of the `'.'` in the sentence. Since you want to copy the `'.'`, you need `i+1` bytes for the characters **plus** 1 extra byte for the null terminator, hence a total size of `i+2` bytes. The `while` loop stop when `j > i`, which first happens when `j == i + 1`, storing `'\0'` to `newbuf[i+1]` has undefined behavior because the last valid byte in `newbuf` is at offset `i`. This undefined behavior may or may not have visible side effects, but it is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtok() to split string. Just type **man strtok**, You will see:

Program source

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       char *str1, *str2, *token, *subtoken;
       char *saveptr1, *saveptr2;
       int j;

       if (argc != 4) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string delim subdelim\n",
                   argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       for (j = 1, str1 = argv[1]; ; j++, str1 = NULL) {
           token = strtok_r(str1, argv[2], &saveptr1);
           if (token == NULL)
               break;
           printf("%d: %s\n", j, token);

           for (str2 = token; ; str2 = NULL) {
               subtoken = strtok_r(str2, argv[3], &saveptr2);
               if (subtoken == NULL)
                   break;
               printf(" --> %s\n", subtoken);
           }
       }

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

An example of the output produced by this program is the following:

```
   $ ./a.out 'a/bbb///cc;xxx:yyy:' ':;' '/'
   1: a/bbb///cc
            --> a
            --> bbb
            --> cc
   2: xxx
            --> xxx
   3: yyy
            --> yyy
```